# Appending rows from one csv to another if their first column matches

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have two csv files with the same rows but different columns:

`$ cat file1`

```
category,a,b,c,d,e
apple,0,0,0,0,0
bear,1,1,1,1,1
```

`$ cat file2`

```
category,f,g,h,i,j
bear,10,10,10,10,10
apple,5,5,5,5,5
```

Expected output:

```
category,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
apple,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5
bear,1,1,1,1,1,10,10,10,10,10
```

Both `file1` and `file2` are unordered and have the same number of matching rows (~15000 rows). `file1` has ~1000 and `file2` has ~16000 columns. I've used the following approach:

```
import csv

with open ("file1.csv") as f:
    first = {rows[0]:rows[1:] for rows in list(csv.reader(f))}


with open("file2.csv") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if row[0] in first:
            first[row[0]].extend(row[1:])

# print(first)
# {'category': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], 'apple': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5'], 'bear': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '10', '10','10', '10', '10']}
```

I feel like I'm getting close but I can't seem to write `first` with the same format as above expected output.

On a side note, does it make sense to sort the files then append? They have exactly the same number of rows and categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close but there are (IIUC) some complicating factors. The main one is that `file_a` and `file_b` are different lengths, and so it’s safe to assume that they may have a disjoint number of categories in Column A. That is, a category (`bear`/`apple` etc.) might exist in one file and not the other.

For this reason, I am using a `defaultdict`. This means that, if the key doesn’t exist, it will be automateically created with an empty list stored against it. If we’ve seen that key before, we just extend the existing list against it. If we haven’t, we treat it exactly the same way but just extend the *default* empty list that exists.

You can test this by putting a completely new row in either `file_a` or `file_b`; the code will go as normal.

Also, by packaging in a function(`build_output`) we only need the `with open()...` code once. If you want to add another file, simply put `output = build_output('file_c.csv', output)`  and it will be added in the same way.

Finally, we’re using the first column as a key in our dictionary and all the rest of the values in the file as the “value”. We need to concatenate these back together as a single list.  We *could* have used the first column as the key and then stored the whole row against that key, but it would make writing it back out difficult without the key appearing multiple times. Instead, enclose the `key` in a list and concatenate it back with the list of values to give a single list that we can write on one row.

```
import csv

from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(list)


def build_output(file_name, output_obj):
    with open(file_name) as infile:
        reader_obj = csv.reader(infile)
        for row in reader_obj:
            output_obj[row[0]].extend(row[1:])
    return output_obj


def write_output(output):
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for key, value in output.items():
            row = [key] + value
            writer.writerow(row)


output = build_output('file_a.csv', output)
output = build_output('file_b.csv', output)
write_output(output)
```

Comment: My files have the same number of matching rows/categories so I don't think defaultdict was necessary for my use case. But thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: @5areductase The defaultdict is no less efficient, is part of the standard library, and gives you protection against that situation _in case_ it exists as a bonus :) You're welcome for the explanation, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @5areductase apologies, yeah, you said they had different numbers of columns, not rows, and I lost track of that while testing the solution.